# How to handle firebase authentication on vue

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-authentication

I’m working with a vuejs project and I’m using firebase oauth authentication.
I’ve already implemented the sign in with popup flow, and the auth state change event listener, it works pretty well.

The thing is, after I sign in, when I refresh/first load the application, as the auth session persists, there’s a time span between the app load and the auth state change is triggered, so even though I’m logged in, I see the login screen for a few seconds before the event is fired and I get redirected to the main page

For example

1. I open the application
2. As I’m not authenticated, I get redirected to `/login`
3. I see the login screen
4. I sign in using the google provider and the popup
5. I get redirected to the main page `/`
6. I refresh the page
7. I get redirected to `/login`
8. As I was already authenticated, the `authStateChange` event fires and I get redirected to the main page, but this happens after a couple seconds

There’s any way to handle that previous state to be able to show a “loading...” or something? I’ve been reading the docs but the only thing I found is using the event listener that I’m already using

Thank y’all in advance!

Comment: Have a look at Section "Handling User State on Page Reload" of this [tutorial](https://savvyapps.com/blog/definitive-guide-building-web-app-vuejs-firebase).

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’ve been doing, my concern is aimed to that time span between the page load, and the moment when the auth state is changed. Before the auth state changes I’m seeing the login screen, I was wondering if there’s a way to know if the user will be authenticated so I can show a “loading” label or something. I’m still trying to find a solution, if I come with something I’ll post it here

Answer (score 0):

Okay y’all, this is the solution I came with:

There’s no way to know if an user will ve logged in until it gets actually logged in and the authStateChange event fires. So the best I could do is, when the user logs in into the application, I store a “EXPECT_LOGIN” value in localStorage, so if I reload the app, and that value it’s true i show a “Loggin in” message with a timeout of, say, 5 seconds. Here we have two possibilities:

1. The event is fired and the user is logged in automatically
2. The timeout is fulfilled and I set the “EXPECT_LOGIN” value to False, then I let the user login manually